# Why are these H the most acidic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

[image: cyclohexa-2,5-dien-1-one]

I don't quite understand why these two hydrogens are the most acidic. From a hybridization perspective, these are connected to a $\mathrm{sp^3}$ carbon (I thought the more s character, the more acidic). So why is it not any of the other hydrogens (connected to $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbon)?

Comment: Consider the structure of phenol, how stable is the phenoxide ion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two hydrogen atoms are acidic, but things change after one of them is lost. But I think that the question was aimed at the acidity of either of the hydrogen atoms and they are equivalent, so let's see why:
[image]

As you can see in the given figure that after abstraction of $\ce{H+}$ the conjugate base can resonate to attain aromaticity. It is this stability that makes the hydrogen atom acidic. Now to remove the second $\ce{H+}$ the story changes, but I would be leaving out that discussion as it has not been asked in the question.

Comment: If the answer smoothens your path of learning chemistry, do take a moment off to accept it.